# Error when using two any functions in if condition

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error, any

this is a very simple(may be silly) question.But I have been trying for an hour on this.Here is a invalid syntax statement i get ,when I use two if conditions with any function.Here is the statement I used.

```
if any(table in sentence for table in (alias_dict["tables"].strip('][').split(', ')))==False and if any(column in sentence for column in (alias_dict["columns"].strip('][').split(', ')))==True:
    print("Hii success")
```

But I am getting the error:

> if any(table in sentence for table in
> (alias_dict["tables"].strip('][').split(', ')))==False and if
> any(column in sentence for column in
> (alias_dict["columns"].strip('][').split(', ')))==True:
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Error (^) is shown near 'and'. I tried giving "&&" as well. I also tried giving paranthesis for whole `any()` as well.But it doesnt seem to work out.I know it might be a silly blunder from my part.Still Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's just `and any(...)`, you can't have another `if`.

Comment: Try using editors like Pycharm or Visual Studio Code etc.; it might be helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `if thing and otherthing`, not `if thing and if otherthing`.

Comparing to `False` is also slightly weird. Try this instead.

```py
if not any(
        table in sentence for table in alias_dict["tables"].strip('][').split(', ')
      ) and any(
        column in sentence for column in alias_dict["columns"].strip('][').split(', ')):
    print("Hii success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give another if in the same if statement!
`if any(table in sentence for table in (alias_dict["tables"].strip('][').split(', ')))==False`

**Your complete code will be:**

```
if any(table in sentence for table in (alias_dict["tables"].strip('][').split(', ')))==False and any(column in sentence for column in (alias_dict["columns"].strip('][').split(', ')))==True:
    print("Hii success")
```

and if you even want to use another if statement, then use **elif** in the next condition

Comment: There is no `elseif` keyword in Python; it's `elif`. But either way, I don't see how that adds any value here.

Comment: @tripleee I corrected it, it should be elif! thanks